# Не получается использовать sympy модуль. Пишет нет такого

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, install, sympy

Вроде по команде установка прошла успешно, выдает что pip Install sympy прошло успешно. Но при команде import sympy делает вид, что не знает такого модуля. Как помочь питону?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `python -m pip install sympy`.

Comment: Это команда введена, и все успешно распаковалось, но тем не менее питон ее подчеркивает и не видит

Comment: Где он это делает? Где не видит?

Comment: WARNING: The script isympy is installed in '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  NOTE: The current PATH contains path(s) starting with `~`, which may not be expanded by all applications.

Comment: Вот при попытке его установить такое пишет, что путь не тот. А как устранить это, не понимаю

Comment: "при попытке его установить"? Что и куда вы ставите?

Comment: команду вашу прописала python -m pip install sympy

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо. То что вы видите - предупреждение. А что не работает?

Comment: type python python is /us/local/bin/python
python3 --version
Python 3.10.5
 which python3
/us/local/bin/python3
 pip --version pip 22.3.1 from /us/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (py thon 3.10)
 pip list
Package
Version
cycler
0.11.0
fonttools
4.36.0
kiwisolver
1.4.4
matplotlib
3.5.3
mpmath
1.2.1
numpy
1.23.2
packaging
21.3
Pillow
9.2.0
pip
22.3.1
pyparsing
3.0.9
python-dateutil 2.8.2 setuptools
63.4.3
six
1.16.0
sympy
1.11.1
wheel
0.37.1
pip show sympy
Name: sympy
Vorcion: 1 11 1

Comment: пишу например import sympy, он подчеркивает, что такого нет  и не выполняет действия в коде

Comment: Где вы это пишите? Кто его подчёркивает?